# From Snowpro certification point of view, is Premier edition still a valid edition?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

From Snowpro certification point of view, is Premier edition still a valid edition ?

As per Snowflake documentation, the valid editions are -

1. Standard
2. Enterprise
3. Business critical / ESD (Enterprise for Sensitive Data)
4. VPS(Virtual Private Snowflake)

Answer (score 0):

Those are the editions.  You might be thinking about support level.  Premium is a support level.

Comment: No - Premium was an edition like other editions for Snowflake. The training guide I received from Snowflake is outdated and still shows Premier as one of the Snowflake editions for customers.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the dates of last updates to [the Snowpro Certification information sheets on their website](https://community.snowflake.com/s/snowprocertifications), the older account editions may still be a part of the information used to form the questions (subject to its relevancy in the exam).

If you have reason to believe the questions about account editions play a part in the certifications, you can reach out to the [email address mentioned in this document (pg. 2)](https://snowforce.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#i0000000hZh2/a/0Z0000001zqh/..n0XdIvHIKHhz9AvjUcgnjUlHF8C7ZkDvlmjO0CFt4) to confirm if the exams have been (or are constantly) updated to reflect currently available information. There does not appear to be a public source of information regarding the update cadence of the exam questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the certification and I can assure that Premier is no longer a valid edition for certification purposes.

Please refer to the page below, to check the valid editions:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-editions

Best,

RG